# Tensorflow module not found in PyCharm

Tags: python, tensorflow, pycharm

i have some problems with tensorflow on my Mac. First of all i notice that i can't install tensorflow using python 3.7, so i changed python version (3.6) . I tried to install tensorflow using virtualenv and it seemed to work, but when i use pycharm, there is not a module named tensorflow. So i changed the project preferences and i added manually tensorflow to the project interpreter (venv python 3.6) but it's not working at all. There are two screenshots about the problem. Sorry for my bad english

## error

[[image: error[1]] 
and project interpreter

[image: Project interpreter]

Comment: could you verify you are indeed using the venv by typing `import os os.system('python --version')` before importing tensorflow?

Comment: Before importing, in the terminal appear the acronym (venv) @Alexis

Comment: i know and yet i'm not sure the consol runs in 3.6 (it cost nothing to verify (i've made this mistake on a venv yesterday as i was running on a consol with a non activated venv

Comment: Ok sorry, i did not understand your reply. So how i can do this? If i type:
' python --version ' the result is 2.7.10 @Alexis

Comment: then you are running a python 2.7 not a 3.6... there is an issue here. i'll try to find out why.

Comment: i think i must change the default version of python, from 2.7 to 3.6

Comment: @Alexisi think that python 2.7 is not the default version that i use in my system. If i type python --version it appear 2.7, instead if i type python3 --version it appear 3.6. So i'm confused

Comment: and just under the python interpreter, can you change also the interpreter of the console? just to be sure... 
And you have run the python --version from your script? else i don't know...

Comment: Btw do not create your custom files under `venv` directory. It contains your virtual environment and PyCharm excludes it by default to prevent unnecessary indexing causing you custom modules to be ignored as well (yellow highlighting).

Comment: @PavelKarateev So what i should do?